# haskell repl case-insensitive autocompletion

Tags: haskell, autocomplete, read-eval-print-loop, case-insensitive

Can i make `cabal repl` autocompletion to be case-insensitive?

Other `cabal repl` autocompletion features matching ones in `zsh` would be very nice as well.